# How to except administrator or a user from everyone in folder permission in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, security

I have set my delete restriction to 'everyone' in folder permission and full control to 'user account' and 'admin' but still i cannot delete files in admin account.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question, you have assigned the following permissions:

- Everyone: Deny Delete
- Administrators: Allow Full Control
- [*User account name*]: Allow Full Control

In that case, yes, you must not be able to delete the affected objects. Permissions with "Deny" type always override permissions with "Allow" type. You must change it to:

- Everyone: Allow Read & Execute
- Administrators: Allow Full Control
- [*User account name*]: Allow Modify